# Is it possible to have a Raspberry Pi work like a much faster arduino

Tags: arduino, real-time, bootloader

Let's imagine you have a real-time problem that you can solve with the Raspberry Pi hardware but you need something much faster than an Arduino. Is it possible to bypass the OS of a Raspberry Pi to have used some kind of bootloader like an Arduino, and run with the same structure in real-time as with Arduino (i.e. no time-sharing), but much faster?

Comment: Have a look at Teensy 4.0, it'll be much easier to set up and program than a bare-metal RPi.

Comment: What task do you actually want implemented?

Comment: First, understanding the limits of what you can and what you can't do. I've tried myself with arduino, but for some applications I found it quite slow.

Comment: Yes, Anono is very slow, get a stm32 board which is 10 times faster then Anono. Anono just makes you stupid. You can let one Rpi coordinate multiple STMs. https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-stm32-arm.html – tlfong01 10 mins ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very much the premise of [Ultibo](https://ultibo.org/).

> **What is Ultibo?**
>
> Imagine if you could have the simplicity and freedom of Arduino with
>   the power and features of a Raspberry Pi. With the ease of a
>   microcontroller and the flexibility of a real computer, Ultibo gives
>   you a platform for creating anything without the limitations of a
>   traditional operating system.

If Ultibo is not what you want there are plenty of other bare-metal (no operating system) examples for the Raspberry Pi.